# including file without ob_start

Tags: php, include

I have small problem.

when i include file without ob_start, head's codes comes in to body. So when i include without ob_start it look's like;

[image]

and when i use ob_start it look's like;

[image]

and my codes with ob_start

```
ob_start();
include("mysql.php"); 
ob_end_clean();
```

I hope it's explained, I dont want ob_start but if i'm not use website look's like first image. and sorry for bad english..

Comment: Ques is; How can i include php files without outer buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete.Still I hope following answer helps you.

[ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) — Turn on output buffering

It is used If you really need to `echo/print` something above your `header/session_start` code than you have to use it.

And to avoid its use you have to confirm that there is nothing (i.e text or even a `space`) above your header or session_start code or it will thrown you the warning as `header already sent`.